# Order of keys of array in JS variable are changing when assigning data from php to JS

Tags: javascript, smarty

I am working on a product detail in **Prestashop**. On product page, I am putting the all attributes defined into system in javascript array.

PHP variable which holds the product attributes is given below:

```
$groups = array(
   '34' => array( //Here key is attribute group id
            'default_attribute_id' => '105', // default attribute id of this group
            'attributes' => array(  // all the attribute with attr id => attr vaue
                  '105' => 'Small',
                  '115' => 'X-Large',
                  '110' => 'Medium'
             ),  
         ),
    .......
);
```

Now the "$groups" variable assigned to javacript variable in tpl file as given below:

```
{addJsDef attributeGroups = $groups}
```

Now when I console the value of "attributeGroups", then it lost its order of attribute ids as in "$groups" variable. The value of in console is given below:

```
var attributeGroups = {
  34: {
       'default_attribute_id': "105",
       'attributes': { //Order of attributes id has changed
             105: "Small",
             110: "Medium",
             115: "X-Large"
       }
     } 
}
```

I have also tried with manually inserting values in "attributeGroups" variable using foreach loop but the result is same.

I dont want to change the order of attribute ids. Can anyone help me on this? Why the order of attribute ids are changing when assigning to javascript variable.

Comment: Order of properties is not guarantied, this is normal. Don't rely on it. If you need fixed order, use array.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As per your suggestion, I have change the that from object to array. But still the result is same. I have also debug the code, the values are assigned into JS variable in correct order but when i print that variable then it is showing data with wrong order (shown in question)

Comment: Array would not have this problem, it means that you did it wrong. But hard to tell without code.

Answer (score 0):

This way it should create simple JS array (which has fixed order of elements):

```
$groups = array(
    '34' => array( //Here key is attribute group id
        'default_attribute_id' => '105', // default attribute id of this group
        'attributes' => array(  // all the attribute with attr id => attr vaue
            ['Small', '105'],
            ['X-Large', '115'],
            ['Medium', '110'],
        ),
    ),
    .......
);
```

You just can not use PHP array index, because it will create associative array, which converts to JS object (as JS has no associative arrays)

The resulting JS should be then:

```
var attributeGroups = {
    34: {
        'default_attribute_id': "105",
        'attributes': [
            ["Small", 105],
            ["X-Large", 115],
            ["Medium", 110]
        ]
    }
}
```

Or you could add a `sort` key to your attributes array, and sort it in JS when you need it (via `Array.sort(callback)`):

```
$groups = array(
    '34' => array( //Here key is attribute group id
        'default_attribute_id' => '105', // default attribute id of this group
        'attributes' => array(  // all the attribute with attr id => attr vaue
            '105' => ['Small', 1],
            '115' => ['X-Large', 2],
            '110' => ['Medium', 3],
        ),
    ),
    .......
);
```

And then sort it when you need it:

```
attributeGroups[34].attributes.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1] - a[2];
})
```